# Trouble finding server root directory

Tags: php

i am working on a php project. I have uploaded the files in the server. When i login to the ftp account, it takes me to the main directory of files. I cannot implement the file download script. because i cannot obtain the root folder. when i use **echo "$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]"**, it shows - "**(/var/chroot/home/content/30/6323230/html/)**". but this does not work for me. if i use file location like - **"$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]/songs/"**, it simply gives error.

Its kinda unknown to me. because previously in another server outputs like - "/home/tskbdcom/public_html". when i log in to this ftp i get the root directory. then i go to "public_html" or "www" directory.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could this be a virtual host issue in apache?

Comment: If you get an error, then you should say what the error is. If your script isn't working, say how it's not working. As it stands now, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: the error is exactly like - Warning: opendir(/var/chroot/home/content/30/6323230/html/songs/2008) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/content/30/6323230/html/tdstar/download.php on line 101

Warning: readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory resource in /home/content/30/6323230/html/tdstar/download.php on line 103
File does not exist. Make sure you specified correct file name.

Comment: may be this is an addon domain and the ftp account is created as a virtual host. If it is so, then what will be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "songs/"
```

no leading slash before directory name because $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] has one slash at the and of path.

*This is not answer to your question this is just reason why you got error using*

```
"$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]/songs/"
```

*Also you have double-quotes inside of double-quotes.*

Comment: I just used it as an example. actually i am using - define('BASE_DIR',$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/songs/'.$_REQUEST['d']); it giving me error - that cannot find the directory or file.

Comment: have you tried to remove leading slash and keep just 'songs/' not '/songs/'?